# How can I use powershell to group process names and show the sum of memory used

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64

I am trying to wrap my head around combining powershell options in order to produce a simple table of the top 10 memory users on my system (server, pc, etc). My PC is Windows 7 with no timeline in site for upgrade to Windows 10 due to Covid 19. I cannot add applications to my work PC that has not gone through a vetting process (read, it takes forever) so most of the time I create my own.

I would like to produce a result that looks something like this:

Count   Name      Memory Sum in MB

---

10      Firefox   5000
3       javaw     1000

The order I would like to be able to select by changing a property in the powershell options. So for example, sort by count, name or memory. My sample table is not set in stone.

I have come across the following 2 pieces of powershell and have been trying to adapt them but get errors.

```
(Get-Process | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum /1gb

 Get-Process | Group-Object -Property Name -NoElement | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
```

For sake of learning, I don't mind seeing an "ugly" version and an optimized version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$proc=ps|select -eXp name;$proc2=@()
$proc|%{
if(!("$($_)" -in $proc2)){$proc2+="$($_)"
$mem=0;ps $_|select -eXp workingSet|%{$mem+=$_/1MB}
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
'Count'=(ps $_ -ea silentlyContinue).Count
'Name'=$_
'Memory in MB'=$mem
}}}
```

Comment: could i talk you into expanding the aliases & short hand names? since aliases are NOT always the same [or even present] in any given profile ... they are a bad idea for anything other than one-off, throwaway uses. plus, they are really poor for teaching ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey they look a little geeky and pretty time saving too... and thanks for the pointer that is not good for newbies

Comment: kool! it will make things much easier to read ... [*grin*]

Comment: I will have to chew on this for a while.. I see techniques I haven't seen yet / before. Running it produces the results I asked about. If anything I would want fewer decimal places for the RAM result and limited to the top 10 or so memory users. Thank you for giving me a learning challenge @Wasif ... [smile]

Comment: @gritts welcome. If this works for you, then consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `PSCustomObject` accelerator was introduced in PowerShell v3 so I don't know if the the output looks like a table in Windows 7 however the following pipeline returns desired properties even in PowerShell v2:

```
Get-Process |
  Group-Object -Property Name -NoElement |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
      ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count= $_.Count
            Name = $_.Name
            'Memory Sum in MB' = [math]::Round(( Get-Process -Name $_.Name |
                Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum /1Mb, 3)
        }
      }    # | Sort-Object -Property 'Memory Sum in MB'
```

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ... I like how the results are displayed. I recognize most of what you utilized here. I think I can take that and adjust further should I desire to report on other properties. I will have to test on my Windows 7 system when I get back to work Monday.